# passing a variable into apply() in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, apply

I am having trouble getting the syntax right for applying a function to a dataframe. I am trying to create a new column in a dataframe by joining the strings in two other columns, passing in a separator. I get the error

```
TypeError: ("apply_join() missing 1 required positional argument: 'sep'", 'occurred at index cases')
```

If I add sep to the apply_join() function call, that also fails:

```
  File "unite.py", line 37, in unite
    tibble_extra = df[cols].apply(apply_join, sep)
NameError: name 'sep' is not defined
```

```py
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

tibble3_csv = """country,year,cases,population
Afghanistan,1999,745,19987071
Afghanistan,2000,2666,20595360
Brazil,1999,37737,172006362
Brazil,2000,80488,174504898
China,1999,212258,1272915272
China,2000,213766,1280428583"""
with StringIO(tibble3_csv) as fp:
    tibble3 = pd.read_csv(fp)
print(tibble3)

def str_join_elements(x, sep=""):
    assert type(sep) is str
    return sep.join((str(xi) for xi in x))

def unite(df, cols, new_var, combine=str_join_elements):
    def apply_join(x, sep):
        joinstr = str_join(x, sep)
        return pd.Series({new_var[i]:s for i, s in enumerate(joinstr)})
  
    fixed_vars = df.columns.difference(cols)
    tibble = df[fixed_vars].copy()
    tibble_extra = df[cols].apply(apply_join)
  
    return pd.concat([tibble, tibble_extra], axis=1) 
table3_again = unite(tibble3, ['cases', 'population'], 'rate', combine=lambda x: str_join_elements(x, "/"))
print(table3_again)
```

Comment: I have modified the program so that apply_join successfully returns a list that should be converted to a DataFrame,.  That df should then be concatenated to another df. I think I need to post a different question to address the failure of converting the list to df and then concatenating that df; is that correct?

Answer (score 5):

Use `lambda` when you have multiple parameters i.e

```
df[cols].apply(lambda x: apply_join(x,sep),axis=1)
```

Or pass parameters with the help of `args` parameter i.e

```
 df[cols].apply(apply_join,args=[sep],axis=1)
```

Comment: tibble_extra = df[cols].apply(apply_join,args=[sep], axis=1)
NameError: name 'sep' is not defined

Comment: Specify your sep like `sep = ','` or `sep='_'`

Comment: I won't know what it is in advance when the method is called; in the example it is called with unite(tibble3, ['cases', 'population'], 'rate', combine=lambda x: str_join_elements(x, "/"))
print(table3_again)

Comment: instead of sep you can pass `','` or `'/'`

Comment: By passing in the combine function to apply_join (instead of sep), I can get a list that needs to be converted to a df and then concatenated to the other df. Doing those last two parts is the problem now.

Comment: it is very good

Answer (score 1):

You just add it into the apply statement:

```
tibble_extra = df[cols].apply(apply_join, sep=...)
```

Also, you should specify the axis. It may work without it, but its a good habit to prevent errors:

```
tibble_extra = df[cols].apply(apply_join, sep=..., axis=1(columns) or 0(rows|default))
```

Comment: File "unite.py", line 32, in apply_join
    joinstr = str_join_elements(x, sep)
  File "unite.py", line 27, in str_join_elements
    return sep.join((str(xi) for xi in x))
AttributeError: ("'ellipsis' object has no attribute 'join'", 'occurred at index 0')